# CANNM PNC Prepare sleep timer

Tags: nm

In CanNM Spec and TR，I don't find this paramter" PNC Prepare sleep timer".
please where can find this parameter in our DaVinci Configurator.Thank you very much.
[image]

please where can find this parameter in our DaVinci Configurator